# Adding item at top of a list using Angular UI-Scroll

Tags: angularjs, virtualscroll, ui-scroll

I am using  [Angular UI scroll](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll). The example I am following is [this one](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll/blob/master/demo/adapter/adapter.html) . It has a demo page [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-scroll/demo/examples/adapter.html). It has a function to add a list item at specific position. Following is the excerpt of the code:

```
        $scope.addToList1 = ->
            $scope.firstListAdapter.applyUpdates (item, scope) ->
                newItem = undefined
                if scope.$index == 2
                    newItem =
                        id: idList1
                        content: 'a new one #' + idList1
                    idList1++
                    return [
                        item
                        newItem
                    ]
                return
```

This function will add list item at 3rd place. However, I am not able to use this one to add element at top ( i.e. to the top of the list ). I tried putting `scope.$index == 0` instead of `scope.$index == 2`. If I use `scope.$index == 1`, it will add element in the second position.  There is also a prepend function in ui-scroll, but I am not sure how to use it to add item always at the top of the list. The newly added item should always be a at the position 1.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add items at the top of the list by using `$index == -1`

```
$scope.addToList1 = ->
    $scope.firstListAdapter.applyUpdates (item, scope) ->
        newItem = undefined
        if scope.$index == -1
            newItem =
                id: idList1
                content: 'a new one #' + idList1
            idList1++
            return [
                item
                newItem
            ]
        return
```